# Monitoring threads in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jvm

I have case where i need to monitor the threads in JVM periodically.
I am planning to use [ThreadMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html).
I could not find information about the consequence of using this bean.
So my questions are

1. Is there performance impact of using this bean.
2. If there is performance impact, is it all the methods on the interface or only some (ex: i see posts regarding usage of getCurrentThreadCpuTime().

Any reference of JDK documentation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned `ThreadMXBean` is good entry to have threads informations and this will not decrease performance or add big overhead, but be careful because method like dumpAllThreadswill use many memory and cpu.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/mxbeans.html